# Can a government stimulus cause a sustained improvement in the economy?

Tags: economics

I was reading [Can Anyone Really Create Jobs?](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/11/06/magazine/job-creation-campaign-promises.html?_r=1&scp=1&sq=can%20goverment%20create%20jobs&st=cse) from the New York Times. In the article, it is argued that, though more spending on the part of consumers is needed to improve the economy, a $400 billion jobs package may not be able to trigger spending patterns that existed before the economic crisis.

> With no new theories, Democrats dusted off the big idea from the Great Depression, John Maynard Keynes’s view that government can create jobs by spending a lot of money. The stimulus, however, has to be borrowed, and it has to be really, truly huge — probably something like $1.5 or $2 trillion — to fill the gap between where the economy is and where it would be if everyone was spending at pre-recession levels. The goal is to goad consumers into spending again. And President Obama’s jettisoned $400 billion jobs package, hard-core Keynesians argue, is nowhere near what it would take to persuade them.

Can a government stimulus cause a sustained improvement in the economy when that stimulus money will have to be borrowed?

Comment: _Food for thought_:  If they give an equal share of that **$400 billion** to the **~307 million US citizens** ( http://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=kf7tgg1uo9ude_&met_y=population ), each person would get **$1,302** which I suspect would encourage a lot of spending.

Comment: @DJClayworth:  Paying off debts _is_ spending, but in the form of a deferred and increased payment (and lower debt should make it possible for the person with that debt to get out of debt sooner, then start spending sooner).  Regarding investments, I agree with you (hopefully the investments would be in the country, but it's difficult to guess where or how everyone will choose to invest).  I do agree that many people would use it to pay off debts or invest, but I suspect that a lot of people will also just see it as a bonus and spend it immediately since many people seem to mismanage money.

Comment: @DJClayworth:  Okay, I'll go along with the macroeconomic point of view (that's an interesting point you raised) as it appears to be reasonable, but I still have a hard time agreeing that paying off debt doesn't stimulate the economy because:  If people have less debt (e.g., because they pay it down sooner), then it logically follows that it will be easier for them to build up more buying power.  _Of course, I'm interested in knowing how I may be mistaken about this as it's clearly an assumption on my part._  =)

Comment: Theoretically paying off debt might make them spend more in the future. But if they don't spend NOW, the economy doesn't grow NOW. The theory says that if we can grow the economy NOW that in itself will cause more people to spend and the economy will continue to recover.

Comment: @DJClayworth:  That makes sense (+1), but I think there is one more factor -- monthly interest payments for more debt are usually higher, and if a portion of the debt is paid off in a lump sum then a restructuring the of debt payments may become an option where it wasn't previously.  Assuming that some people will take this option, that should result in at least some people having a little bit more buying power fairly quickly.  _Perhaps one important missing aspect here is an understanding of how much debt most people have?_

Comment: @Randolf - don't have a cite right now but the aggregate personal det is way bigger than the stimulus, therefore using that lump sum would merely decrease the debt magnitude and therefore not increas purchasing power that much.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Experience says most people in the US would either spend it practically before they got the check, or use it to pay off debt just to put it back on the credit card.  But I still contend that if everyone saved it or paid off debt that it would actually help the economy... there is no way to prove this since it is virtually impossible to test though  I would be surprised to see greater than 10% use the money for saving or paying off debt and have not spent it within 4 months.

Comment: Perhaps the question needs to be posed a little more carefully. The classic example of the government paying some people to dig holes and other people to fill them creates jobs, but not in a sense which generates more wealth--i.e the economy does not grow in a meaningful way and it won't help things to get better.

Comment: I'm voting to close because the question is too vague - you can parse "create jobs" any way you want (e.g. @dmckee 's hole diggers fits the bill in some parsings, as does Solyndra), and without specifying desirable/acceptable long term effects you can't answer.

Comment: @dmckee: I concur. As written, the question was basically meaningless. I edited the question to actually represent a claim one could be skeptical of.

Comment: @DJClayworth The Australian Government gave every taxpayer earning less than $80K a one-time $950 cash bonus in 2008-9 during the GFC. This move has been widely lauded by economists and is cited as one of the measures that helped Australia weather the GFC so successfully, [because people spent their bonus](http://www.theaustralian.com.au/business/economics/no-doubt-fiscal-stimulus-supported-economy/story-e6frg926-1225831959995).

Comment: Sharing my ignorance, it matters what the jobs are. It's easy to create jobs - just break a lot of windows. Beyond that, if there's perceived inflation, people want to get rid of money, causing more inflation. If deflation, the opposite happens. So that's an unstable system. There's got to be a way to stabilize it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The truth is that this is a complicated question, and one on which economists disagree. A Google search will find learned papers in support of both sides. No amount of debate by a few guys on a Q&A site is going to produce a definitive answer.

Sources saying Yes:

- [Former vice chairman of the Federal Reserve in the Wall Street Journal](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052702303635604576392023187860688.html)
- [A blogger at The Economist](http://www.economist.com/blogs/democracyinamerica/2011/08/stimulus-thinking)
- [Anonymous article in the Washington Post Business](http://www.washingtonpost.com/business/economy/spin-meter-gop-says-government-money-doesnt-create-jobs-_-except-millions-of-defense-jobs/2011/11/04/gIQABOI0kM_story.html)
- [Briefing from the Center for American Progress](http://www.americanprogress.org/issues/2011/09/yes_we_can.html)
- [Information Analyses, Stanford Univ., CA. Inst. for Research on Educational Finance and Governance (1983)](http://www.eric.ed.gov/ERICWebPortal/search/detailmini.jsp?_nfpb=true&_&ERICExtSearch_SearchValue_0=ED235568&ERICExtSearch_SearchType_0=no&accno=ED235568)

Sources saying No:

- [A columnist, The Globe and Mail](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/opinions/opinion/governments-cant-spend-people-back-to-work/article2160066/)
- [A columnist, Forbes Magazine](http://www.forbes.com/sites/charleskadlec/2011/03/07/to-increase-job-creation-reduce-government-spending/)
- [CBC report quoting the Fraser institute](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/story/2010/03/23/fraser-institute-report.html)

Sources saying Don't Know:

- [Article for the *Journal of Economic Literature* forum](http://econ.ucsd.edu/~vramey/research/JEL_Fiscal_14June2011.pdf)
- [2007 Report from the Department of Economics and Political Economy Research Institute (PERI)](http://ww.fpif.org/reports/071001-jobcreation.pdf)
- [2009 Article in the New York Times by a Harvard Professor of Economics and former President Bush adviser](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/01/11/business/economy/11view.html)
- [Senior editor of Forbes magazine, including multiple links to economic studies.](http://www.forbes.com/sites/danielfisher/2011/08/01/economists-agree-nobody-knows-real-effect-of-government-spending-cut/)

That last NY Times link is worth reading, as it goes some of the way towards explaining why this simplistic question is not helpful, and not even the one we should be asking.

There are also available many highly technical economics papers seeking to answer this very question, but I am not competent to recommend any.

Comment: It's the best answer you are going to get on this site. Serious, if we don't know what the answer is, the right answer is "we don't know". Of course someone will write "definitely yes" or "definitely no" and both of those answers will be wrong.

Comment: +1 because I particularly like the part about "**No amount of debate by a few guys on a Q&A site is going to produce a definitive answer.**"

Comment: If there is no clear evidence going either way, then a good portrayal of the evidence for each side is the best answer possible. However, currently, all the information is on other sites. Please bring that information here, either by summarizing the facts or by quoting relevant passages.

Comment: +-0 I would be much happier if this was citing published papers or economists rather than journalists.

Comment: @KitSunde - I agree referencing multiple (unreferenced) original works of opinion to support a claim of truth seems like cheating.

Comment: @KitSunde There are plenty of published papers on the subject, but they are far too technical for me. Most are concerned with detailed analyses of tiny little bits of the question. Even then they don't necessarily come to a definite conclusion.

Answer (score 8):

This question is known as the great debate in economics, and it started back in the early 20th century between two leading economists, [John Maynard Keynes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Maynard_Keynes) and [Friedrich Hayek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Hayek). The debate was over how best to spur a sluggish economy. Keynes proposed that the government could directly spur a stalled economy through direct investment and stimulus while Hayek countered that such moves might provide a temporary boost, but were not healthy, had unexpected consequences, and simply delayed the day of reckoning.

For more background on the Keynes-Hayek debate (albeit with a bit of bias toward Hayek), read Cochran and Glahe's, [The Hayek-Keynes Debate – Lessons for Current Business Cycle Research](http://www.mellenpress.com/mellenpress.cfm?bookid=4020&pc=9). For a more human-interest look at the lives of these two men and how their  theories shaped modern economics, see Wapshott's [Keynes-Hayek: The Clash That Defined Modern Economics](http://books.wwnorton.com/books/Keynes-Hayek/).

Unfortunately, when discussing world-wide macro-economics the system is so large, interconnected, and complex that it is impossible to come up with a definitive answer to these types of questions, which is why this Keynes-Hayek debate rages on. There's not a simple positive or negative test that can be applied. For insight on this complexity and the hopelessness of making conclusive statements from such uncertainty, refer to Nassim Taleb's book, [The Black Swan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Swan_%28Taleb_book%29).

So to answer your question, "Can a government end a recession through job creation?" the honest answer is, "It depends who you ask."

Comment: References please...

Comment: I added some references, but honestly, this question is like asking, "Who would win in a race, Superman or The Flash?"

Comment: Obviously Speedy Gonzolas would be the actual winner of such a race. Duh.

Comment: @dmckee - Speedy Gonzolas isn't real, so he can't win the race. Excellent answer - +1.

Comment: The Black Swan isn't peer-reviewed research. It is not even an attempt at empirical research and doesn't address the literature well. Not a very reliable source for determining the appropriate level of "hopelessness" that we should have at our ability to make conclusive statements.